# TFS2010 Xaml Build Controller With TFS 2015

Tags: xaml, tfs-2015

We are attempting to upgrade our rather old TFS environment from TFS2008 to TFS2015. The upgrade of the server and database is not a problem and is fine.

The issue is our build machine. This is still a Windows 2003 Server that is running Visual Studio 2010 and VB6. We still have a need to use this build machine to build legacy VB6 projects. We have installed the TFS2010 XAML build controller on this server and successfully connected it to our test TFS2015 server. However when we try to run a Xaml build, (any Xaml build regardless of whether it builds VB6 or .NET) we get the following error message almost straight away.

`TF900560: Could not start build: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfsBuild.TargetsNotLogged'`.

The XAML build are using the 'UpgradeTemplate.xaml' template and using the TFSBuild.proj we used under Visual Studio 2010.

We have a also set up a TFS2015 build controller on another (Server 2012) machine and that successfully starts the build process. However, our VB6 projects use a lot of third party components that will not install on Server 2012 so we can't use that.

Has anyone ever set up this kind of arrangement before? Is there anything we are missing or are doomed in this scenario? Obviously, we'd like to move away from VB6 apps, but that is not possible in the medium term.

Comment: Did you do some customization on the 'UpgradeTemplate.xaml' template, like add some custom activities? It seems that something wrong with your build process template, could you please try to use the new build template?

Comment: No, everything is out of the box.

Comment: You said that TFS 2015 build controller could start this build, so why you don't update the TFS 2010 build controller to TFS 2015 build controller?

Comment: As I mentioned, the VB6 projects we need to build use a number of third party controls, which are rather old. The installers for these will not run on 64bit OS so we need to retain out 2010 Build Controller which is on Windows Server 2003.